# Возврат дублированных значений в список друг за другом

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Sub CreateTable()
 Dim bf As Boolean
 Dim aTable(), aRes()
 Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long
 With Worksheets("List1")   ' List s tabulkou, kde se hleda
 i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 aTable = .Range("A1:P" & i).Value ' tabulka do pole

ReDim aRes(1 To i + 1, 1 To 1) ' velikost pole
End With



For i = 1 To UBound(aTable)  ' od 1 do poctu radky tabulky
If aTable(i, 1) <> Empty Then ' kdyz neni prazdna
   If aTable(i, 4) = "Depo" And aTable(i, 8) = "CZK" _
     Or aTable(i, 4) = "Loan" And aTable(i, 8) = "CZK" Then

    aRes(i, 1) = aTable(i, 7)

      End If
    End If


 Next i



 ' upload vysledku na list do sloupce J
  Worksheets("List2").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes
  Range("A1").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Interest"

End Sub
```

Добрый день. Есть такой вот код. Он сверяет два условия, и если они верны возвращает значения с 7 столбца на другой лист. 
Мне надо сделать так, чтобы значения возвращались начиная с A2 подряд и при этом дублировались. ( так как вы можете видеть на 2-ой картинке)

Прошу помощи.

[image: первая картинка, где сверяются условия, и отсюда же берутся значения]

[image: как должен работать]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CreateTable()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim R1 As Long
    Dim R2 As Long

    Set WB = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set WS1 = WB.Worksheets("List1")
    Set WS2 = WB.Worksheets("List2")

    R1 = 1
    R2 = 1
    While Not IsEmpty(WS1.Cells(R1, 1))
        If (WS1.Cells(R1, 4).Value = "Depo" Or WS1.Cells(R1, 4).Value = "Loan") _
                                            And WS1.Cells(R1, 8).Value = "CZK" Then
            WS2.Cells(R2, 1).Value = WS1.Cells(R1, 7).Value
            WS2.Cells(R2 + 1, 1).Value = WS1.Cells(R1, 7).Value
            R2 = R2 + 2
        End If
        R1 = R1 + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает, как часы!

Answer (score 0):

А ведь мой код. Только Вы переменные лишние оставили. Ищите различия :)

```
Sub CreateTable()
Dim aTable(), aRes()
Dim i As Long, k As Long
    With Worksheets("List1")   ' List s tabulkou, kde se hleda'
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        aTable = .Range("A1:P" & i).Value ' tabulka do pole
    End With

    ReDim aRes(1 To i * 2, 1 To 1) ' velikost pole' увеличили размерность массива с запасом'
    k = 1: aRes(k, 1) = "Interest"

    For i = 1 To UBound(aTable)  ' od 1 do poctu radky tabulky'
        If aTable(i, 1) <> Empty Then ' kdyz neni prazdna'
            If aTable(i, 4) = "Depo" And aTable(i, 8) = "CZK" _
                            Or aTable(i, 4) = "Loan" And aTable(i, 8) = "CZK" Then
                k = k + 1: aRes(k, 1) = aTable(i, 7)
                k = k + 1: aRes(k, 1) = aTable(i, 7)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ' upload vysledku na list do sloupce J'
    Worksheets("List2").Range("A1").Resize(k, 1).Value = aRes ' только до k-й записи'
End Sub
```

Comment: условие немного поменялось, но решил взять ваш код за основу, спасибо за объяснение :)